# Laravel Auth::user relationship

Tags: laravel

In **Laravel**, i´m trying to show relation elements between **Auth::user** (*Users*) and *Departments*. In **User** table i have *id*, *name*, and *department_id*. In **Departments** table I have *id* and *name*.

In user model i create

```
public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Department');
    }
```

Then, in blade template I try

> Auth::user()->department

But return null and doesn´t show *linked* *departments*. Null is incorrect, all *users* have *departments*. Soo, ¿Any help? ¿What´s wrong in relation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add 'department_id' as a second parameter ($foreignKey) when calling belongsTo method, because it will searching for departmento_id by default.

```
public function departamento()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Departamento', 'department_id');
}
```

Or just rename User::departamento() method to User::department()

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Departamento');
}
```

Comment: In fact, you must pass the foreign id since the table is not compliant to Laravel's Eloquent way of relating tables. In this case, if the foreign id is not "singulartablename_id" it won't work.

Answer (score 30):

You can try this `User::with('departmento')->find(Auth::id());`

Comment: Can i use User::with('departament')->find(Auth::id()); in boot to share variable in all templates?

Comment: In your "Controller/BaseController" add folowwing code:
`public function __construct() {
       $user = User::with('departament')->find(Auth::id());
       View::share('user', $user);
    }`

Btw, It's not a good idea.

Comment: There is no point is querying the database since the Auth have already done that! The missing point is that the author had a foreign key not complaint to Laravel's Eloquent way of relating tables. In this case "singulartablename_id".

Answer (score 18):

This method uses less queries - the others go after the user table twice:

```php
auth()->user()->load(['department']);
```

Comment: It's not working i am getting error..
Class "App\Models\ResellerUserDetailModel" not found.
form where you load "load method" ?

Answer (score 3):

Relation works with Model. Auth uses the session it not uses relation

Use `User` Model instead

```
  optional(User::find(Auth::id())->departmento)->department_name
```

Comment: I use a global variable 'user' with Auth::user() to avoid to repeat code and can show/use actual user in all templates. So your answer is correct but i need it to send Auth::id in all templates...

Comment: As you already using `Auth::user()->departmento` you just need to replace with above code

Comment: {{optional(User::find(Auth::id())->departamento)->name}} Return null

Comment: Use `\Auth` instead